# Adjoining elements to $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following is a question from Artin:
Describe the rings obtained by adjoining $\alpha$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that 
a) $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$
b) $\alpha^2+1=0$
c) $\alpha^2+\alpha=0$
This question has quite a few [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124964/672301) on MSE. For part b) they are reasoning that because $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, hence $\alpha=1$ and  $\mathbb{F}_2[\alpha]=\mathbb{F}_2$.
But Artin gave an example showing that this need not be the case: adjoining $\alpha$ to $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ if $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^2-3=0$ produces the ring $\mathbb{F}_{11}\times \mathbb{F}_{11}$.

On the other hand, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657632/672301) I don't see how $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)\cong \mathbb{F}_4$ for part a).

Comment: You must be misreading something, $x^2+x+1\ne (x+1)^2$.

Comment: If you will _carefully read_ the answer  on Math.SE that you cite, you wil see that nowhere does it claim that $x^2+x+1 = (x+1)^2$ in $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my carelessness. I have edited the question now.

Comment: I know that $4 = 2^2$, but seeing $\mathbb F_4$ instead of $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ just makes me wonder what's going on and uncertain that everyone is referring to the same things.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, I'd like to begin by discussing a similar idea of attaching elements to a field, however I want to use $\mathbb{R}$, because I think the notion of square root and roots of polynomials etc is more familiar here.

I will discuss two cases:

i) $\mathbb{R}$ adjoined with the element $\alpha$ where $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^2 + 6\alpha + 5 = 0$

ii) $\mathbb{R}$ adjoined with the element $\alpha$ where $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^2 + 1 = 0$

First case, if $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^2 + 6\alpha + 5 = (\alpha + 5)(\alpha + 1)= 0$ then you know that $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, so adjoining $\alpha$ to $\mathbb{R}$ isn't doing to do anything, since what we have is
$$\mathbb{R}(\alpha) = \{ x + y\alpha : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{r : r \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
the latter equals is because we can just combine $x$ and $y\alpha$, they are both real numbers.

On the other hand, if we adjoin $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2 + 1 = 0$ then you know from school or elsewhere that there is no real number satisfying $x^2 + 1 = 0$ (we know that this is $\pm i$, and there's no harm in just thinking of $\alpha$ as $i$ here if you wish.)

The point is that now that
$$\mathbb{R}(\alpha) = \{ x + y\alpha : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\} \overbrace{=}^{\text{using }\alpha \leftrightarrow i} = \{ x + yi : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\} = \mathbb{C}$$

and you may have seen this result, namely $\mathbb{C} \cong \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2+1)}$.

What was the difference in i) and ii)? In i) the roots of the polynomials already belonged to $\mathbb{R}$, so we weren't adding anything new by adjoining it, however in ii) $\alpha$ was not an element of $\mathbb{R}$, so adjoining it extended our ring (actually a field, but anyway).

Now back to your case of adjoining elements to $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{\bar{0},\bar{1}\}$, perhaps I will talk through $a)$ here and let you think about $b)$ and $c)$.

For $a)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2 + x + 1$, we check if our elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$ are roots, we have $\bar{0}^2 + \bar{0} + 1 = 1 \neq 0$ and $\bar{1}^2 + \bar{1} + 1 = 1 \neq 0$. Therefore $\alpha$ is not an element of $\mathbb{F}_2$, so adjoining it is actually extending our field, and not just adjoining an element which is already in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

So for $a)$ we have $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha) = \{x + y\alpha : x,y \in \mathbb{F}_2 \} = \frac{\mathbb{F}[X]}{(X^2+X+1)} =: \mathbb{F}_4$.

Let me know if this makes sense, and if there's anything that is unclear

Comment: In the $\alpha^2+6\alpha+5=0$ example, according to Artin, this would be the ring $\{a\alpha+b\mid a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ along with the relation that $\alpha$ satisfies.
I think there is a difference in the way we are defining the process of adjoining a element.
Also, I still do not see how $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)=\mathbb{F}_4$. Can you show the isomorphism explicitly?

Comment: Yea this is true, however $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ already, so $\{a\alpha+b:a,b,\in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ d : d \in \mathbb{R} \}$. An explicit example of this would be to take $\alpha = \pi$, or any real number you like. You see that the sets are the same.

Comment: Regarding $\mathbb{F}_4$, in some sense $\mathbb{F}_4 = \mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ by definition, but I can try explain it more. So elements in $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ are represented by elements: $0$, $1$, $\alpha$, $\alpha + 1$ (there are no more e.g $\alpha^2$ isn't a new element since $\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$, so it's already included). You can check that these $4$ elements along with the relation  $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ satisfy all axioms of a field. It has $4$ elements, so it is $\mathbb{F}_4$

Comment: Example: If you want the inverse for $\alpha$, notice that we have $\alpha(\alpha+1) = \alpha^2 + \alpha$, using the relation we get that this is equal to $1$, thus $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$ are inverses to each other.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{F}_2[\alpha] / (\alpha^2 + 1)$ (the *ring* that you get by adjoining an element $\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha^2 + 1 = 0$) is a four-element ring.  Its addition table is
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+ & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \beta \\\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \beta \\
1 & 1 & 0 & \beta & \alpha \\
\alpha & \alpha & \beta & 0 & 1 \\
\beta & \beta & \alpha & 1 & 0
\end{array}
and its multiplication table is
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \beta \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \beta \\
\alpha & 0 & \alpha & 1 & \beta \\
\beta & 0 & \beta & \beta & 0
\end{array}
because (for example) $\alpha \cdot \beta = \alpha \cdot (\alpha + 1) = \alpha^2 + \alpha = \alpha + 1 = \beta$.  Perhaps you can convince yourself that this is the same ring as $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2)$, and the same as the ring
$$
\left \{ 0, I_2, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$
whose elements are certain matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and perhaps there are other ways to describe it as well.

The same process can be used in the other two parts: start with $0, 1, \alpha$ and begin adding and multiplying elements you have already to create new ones; the process terminates very quickly (all three rings have only four elements).

The confused answers in your first link are looking for a field extension (but this is not what the question asks for); this is reasonably clearly sorted out in the second link.